# Blank space at beginning of <title> tag?

Tags: php, templates, html, title

The HTML output of all my WordPress pages has a blank space at the beginning of my `<title>` tag. You can see the effect [here](https://www.dcturano.com/faq/).

My header template contains this:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

And roduces this:

```
<title> FAQ</title>
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your *site's title* is empty. Fill it out or try for example:

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title )
{
    return trim( $title );
} );
```

to remove the blank space in front.

For your setup, the following part of `wp_title()` is responsible for the blank space:

```
$title = $prefix . implode( " $sep ", $title_array );
```

So when you're on a single page, like `FAQ`, this will give you:

```
$title = ' ' . implode( " ", array( 'FAQ' ) );
```

or

```
$title = ' FAQ';
```